# Method that will construct an object, but isn't a constructor

Tags: c++

I'm playing with immutable structures in C++. Say I wanted to move `mathematics` into the `zippy` class - is that possible? It constructs a zippy, but the function couldn't be a constructor. Does it have to live outside the class?

```
struct zippy
{
    const int a;
    const int b;
    zippy(int z, int q) : a(z), b(q) {};
};

zippy mathematics(int b)
{
    int r = b + 5;
    //imagine a bunch of complicated math here
    return zippy(b, r);
}

int main()
{
    zippy r = mathematics(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps make it a `static` member function?

Comment: some nitpicking: you dont want to construct a class, but you want to construct an object / instance of the class

Comment: It can "live inside of it", but it cannot depend on a valid instance of `zippy` when called.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude tried that, can't do, eg: static zippy(int r) { zippy(r, r + 5);}

Comment: @ProbablyAStupidQuestion - That's not what SomeProgrammerDude suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you usually do in that case is expose a public static method that returns a new object:

```
struct zippy
{
    static zippy mathematics(int b);
    const int a;
    const int b;
    zippy(int z, int q) : a(z), b(q) {};
};

zippy zippy::mathematics(int b)
{
    int r = b + 5;
    //imagine a bunch of complicated math here
    return zippy(b, r);
}
```

The naming is off here but you get the idea.

Which can be called without needing an instance of `zippy` and create a new `zippy` object:

```
zippy newZippy = zippy::mathematics(42);
```

Comment: Love it. Awesome. Thanks.